# Multiple function composition

Tags: java, generics, java-8, functional-programming, type-erasure

Today I encountered a following Java assignment, and I can't figure out how to get past type erasure.

The task is to create a generic InputConverter class, which takes an input of type T and converts it using chain of multiple functions received as a method argument. It has to support a following notation:

```
Function<String, List<String>> lambda1 = ...;
Function<List<String>, String> lambda2 = ...;
Function<String, Integer> lambda3 = ...;

String input = ...;

List<String> res1 = new InputConverter(input).convertBy(lambda1);

Integer res2 = new InputConverter(input).convertBy(lambda1, lambda2, lambda3);
```

This is what I came up with:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class InputConverter<T> {
    private final T input;

    public InputConverter(T input) {
        this.input = input;
    }

    public <B> B convertBy(Function<T, ?> first, Function<?, ?>... functions) {
        var res = first.apply(input);

        Function<?, B> composed = Arrays.stream(functions)
            .reduce(Function::andThen)
            .orElse(Function.identity());

        return composed.apply(res);
    }

}
```

This doesn't work of course, since I can't find a way to determine the return type of the last function.

Notes:

- InputConverter should define only one `convertBy` method, so method overloading is not an option.
- This method should return the result of last function in the chain without the need of explicit casting.

Comment: are you sure the assignment is to have any number of functions as parameter? (if it's a fixed number, it's of course much much easier)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, according to task's author the correct solution is this:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class InputConverter<T> {
    private final T input;

    public InputConverter(T input) {
        this.input = input;
    }

    public <B> B convertBy(Function<T, ?> first, Function... functions) {
        var res = first.apply(input);

        Function<Object, B> composed = Arrays.stream(functions)
            .reduce(Function::andThen)
            .orElse(Function.identity());

        return composed.apply(res);
    }

}
```

Which is not satisfying to me at all. It allows for using vararg parameters, but using raw, unparameterized `Function` makes no sense. [Nikolas Charalambidis' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64921696/11618307) is a much better solution as we preserve return type information and safety.

Comment: Hey, that's a good one! I have completely forgotten to the raw parameters. Have my +1 for helping the OP.

Answer (score 3):

**Problem**

You would need to chain the generics for each number of expected functions and chain the generic parameters as on the snippet below with five functions:

```
public <D> E convertBy(
    Function<T, A> first, Function<A, B> second, Function<B, C> third, 
    Function<C, D> fourth, Function<D, E> fifth) {
    ...
}
```

However, this is not possible for unknown number of parameters (varargs). There is no such thing as "vargenerics" which would dynamically create and chain the generic parameters as above.

---

**Solution**

You can instead treat the `InputConverter` as a *builder* instead which returns self with each `convertBy` call and finally packs a result. This recursive behavior allows indefinite number of calls. Try it out:

```
public static class InputConverter<T> {

    private final T data;

    public InputConverter(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public <U> InputConverter<U> convertBy(Function<T, U> function) {
        return new InputConverter<>(function.apply(data));
    }

    public T pack() {
        return data;
    }
}
```

Pretty neat, isn't it? Let's see the usage on a minimal sample:

```
// let lambda1 split String by characters and create a List
Function<String, List<String>> lambda1 = str -> Arrays.stream(str.split(""))
                                                      .collect(Collectors.toList());
// let lambda2 get the first item
Function<List<String>, String> lambda2 = list -> list.get(0);

// let lambda3 parse a String into the Integer
Function<String, Integer> lambda3 = Integer::parseInt;

String input = "123";                                   // out sample numeric input

List<String> res1 = new InputConverter<String>(input)   // don't forget the generics
    .convertBy(lambda1)
    .pack();

Integer res2 = new InputConverter<String>(input)
    .convertBy(lambda1)
    .convertBy(lambda2)
    .convertBy(lambda3)
    .pack();

System.out.println(res1);                               // [1, 2, 3]
System.out.println(res2);                               // 1
```

Comment: That's what I thought of at first, but the task clearly specifies that convertBy should work as I described. I guess that the author didn't check if it's possible to accomplish

Comment: What kind of Java task assignment it is? If it comes from a teacher, I'd like to learn how to implement it as well. If it's either a personal or work task, you should better get convinced there is no solution achieving it with such restrictions (ot at least I am not aware of any). However, the question itself is very interesting.

Comment: It's my friend's school assignment. I'll post the answer here if there's any